# Why does edit list with stream filter peek collect work?

Tags: java, stream

I made some piece of code, which I don't understand why it works and I cannot find clear answer. Here is my code:

```
    log.debug("before");
    for (Employee e : this.employees) {
        log.debug(e.toString());
    }
    employees
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getUuid().equals(event.getEmployeeUuid()))
            .peek(e -> {
                e.setPosition(event.getPosition());
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    log.debug("after");
    for (Employee e : this.employees) {
        log.debug(e.toString());
    }
```

and here is output:

```
before
Employee(uuid=aaa, position=Lord)
Employee(uuid=bbb, position=Employee)
after
Employee(uuid=aaa, position=Overlord)
Employee(uuid=bbb, position=Employee)
```

So my general question is why does it work? I noticed this behavior accidentally and it works only when `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is present at the end of stream processing. Please notice, that there is no explicit assigning output of stream to `this.employees` list.

Comment: Because the list holds _references_ to each `Employee` instance. The stream iterates over those references and modifies them. And the reason `collect` is necessary is because it's a _terminal operation_, whereas `peek` is not. A `Stream` won't execute unless a terminal operation is called.

Comment: Ok, and when I add `List<Employee> newList = employees ....` at the beginning `newList` holds only filtered elements. Ok, I did some additional reading on this. Thanks! Please put this as answer and let me mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `employees` list contains *references* to each `Employee` element. The stream simply iterates over those references and puts them through the pipeline. Your `peek` operation has the [side-effect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) of modifying the position property of each `Employee` allowed through by `filter`. Everywhere you have a reference to those `Employee` instances will see that modification—including the original `employees` list. For more information, see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

The reason you didn't see any changes until you added a call to `collect` is because `collect` is a [*terminal operation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), whereas `filter` and `peek` are not. A `Stream` will not be executed until a terminal operation is invoked.